# Ошибка ассоциации двух моделей

Tags: веб-программирование, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Я хочу что бы при создании поста можно было выбрать автора. У меня есть модель Post и Author. 
В модели автора прописал `has_many :posts`, а в модели поста `belongs_to :author`. В вьюхе формы создал список авторов `<%= form.select(:author, Author.all.collect {|p| [ p.first_name] }) %>`.
В контроллере поста прописал:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :title, :content, :picture, :author)
end
```

Однако, при создании поста получаю ошибку `Author(#70151313190260) expected, got "AuthorName" which is an instance of String(#47111701634520)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы форма заработала, вам надо передать `author_id`, ведь именно через это поле реализована связь `belongs_to`.

```
# collection_select более удобный хелпер, имхо
<%= form.collection_select(:author_id, Author.all, :id, :first_name) %>

# не забудьте добавить author_id в permitted params
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :title, :content, :picture, :author_id)
end
```